# How do I change the focus on buttons of JFace WizardPage?

Tags: java, focus, jface

I have implemented a JFace Wizard with 2 WizardPages.

By default, the first WizardPage has these 4 Buttons:

- Back (disabled)
- Next (focused)
- Cancel
- Finish (disabled)

Now I want to set the default focus on the Cancel Button. How do I do that?

Removing the focus and setting it to some Control of the page's content would also be ok.

I tried setting the focus to a Button in the content layout of the WizardPage, but this only sets me a second focus on the `immediateButton`. The focus on the Next button is still there, and the Next button reacts to pressing enter, which is what I want to avoid.

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    super.setVisible(visible);
    if (visible) {
        immediateButton.setFocus();
    }
}
```

How can I access the Dialog buttons and change their focus?

Comment: You can disable the next button - would that be good enough?

Comment: No... unfortunately not. I want it to be enabled, but not focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Next button does not actually have focus, rather it is the Shell Default button.

The logic in `WizardDialog` makes either Next or Finish the default button and there does not seem to be a way to change this.

You may be able to override this by calling `getShell().setDefaultButton(button)` in your wizard page.

Update: Testing this you can do it in `setVisible` but you need to use `Display.asyncExec` to make the code run at the right time:

```
final Shell shell = getShell();

shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> shell.setDefaultButton(immediateButton));
```

above is for Java 8, for Java 7 or earlier:

```
shell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable()
   {
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
       shell.setDefaultButton(immediateButton); 
     }
   });
```

Comment: What do I pass as the button argument? My `immediateButton`? Or is there a way to get the Cancel button?

Comment: You can't get at the `WizardDialog` buttons easily so it would have to be your `immediateButton`. `null` is also accepted but has complicated rules about what it will do.